# Mongodb aggregate - match _id from array with another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have 2 collections in mongodb: "pay" and "tickets"
The data is like this:

For pay:

```
{
     _id: new ObjectId("121"),
     tickets:[
     {
     _id: new ObjectId("1")
     }     
  ]
}
```

For tickets:

```
{
   _id: new ObjectId("1"),
   name: "xyz"
}
```

Now I want aggregate function to match
`pay.tickets[0]._id` with `tickets._id`

and get all the keys from tickets collection

desired output

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("121"),
    tickets:[
    {
    _id: new ObjectId("1"),
    name:"xyz"
   }     
  ]
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: have u checked $lookup `db.pay.aggregate([ { "$lookup": { "from": "tickets", "localField": "tickets._id", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "tickets" } } ])`

Comment: @cmgchess Yes I did, Not working. Also won't it be tickets[0]._id as it is in array?(Both are not working though)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PJZgxUZTkJ2

Comment: Thankyou got it. Got where the problem was, thankyou for the solution.
@cmgchess